# Accessing currentUser data in firebase_auth plugin version 0.2.0

Tags: dart, firebase-authentication, flutter, dart-async

In my app, I have a drawer with a **UserAccountsDrawerHeader**, which I feed its properties by simply getting the x property from **FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.x**

In the latest [firebase_auth 0.2.0](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth)  version  , where currentUser() is async.

I have been trying for several hours to store the information of the currently logged user and have not yet reached the correct way to do this.

I understand that I can access them by something like the following:

```
   Future<String> _getCurrentUserName() async {
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  return user.displayName;
}
```

...

```
new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(accountName: new Text(_getCurrentUserName()))
```

I understand that these code snippets will give type mismatch, but I am just trying to illustrate what I am trying to do.

What am I missing exactly that is preventing me from reaching a solution?

**Update**

```
class _MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;
  Pages _page;
  String _currentUserName;
  String _currentUserEmail;
  String _currentUserPhoto;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _states();
    controller = new TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
    controller.addListener(_select);
    _page = pages[0];
  }
```

**My method**

I just coupled the auth state with my previously implemented TabBar state

```
   _states() async{
     var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
     var name = user.displayName;
     var email = user.email;
     var photoUrl = user.photoUrl;
    setState(() {
      this._currentUserName=name;
      this._currentUserEmail=email;
      this._currentUserPhoto=photoUrl;
      _page = pages[controller.index];
    });
  }
```

**My Drawer**

```
drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(accountName: new Text(_currentUserName)  ,
              accountEmail: new Text (_currentUserEmail),
              currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(
               backgroundImage: new NetworkImage(_currentUserPhoto),
              ),
```

Here is the **exception** I get from the debug console

```
I/flutter (14926): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (14926): The following assertion was thrown building MyTabs(dirty, state: _MyTabsState#f49aa(tickers:
I/flutter (14926): tracking 1 ticker)):
I/flutter (14926): 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 207 pos 15: 'data != null': is not
I/flutter (14926): true.
I/flutter (14926): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
```

**Update 2:**

This is how I modified the google sign in function from the firebase examples:

```
    Future <FirebaseUser> _testSignInWithGoogle() async {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
      await googleUser.authentication;
//checking if there is a current user
      var check = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      if (check!=null){
        final FirebaseUser user = check;
        return user;
      }
      else{
      final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      assert(user.email != null);
      assert(user.displayName != null);
      assert(!user.isAnonymous);
      assert(await user.getToken() != null);

      return user;
    }
    }
```

**Update 3:**

My main function

```
void main() {
      runApp(
          new MaterialApp(
        home: new SignIn(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          "/SignUp":(BuildContext context)=> new SignUp(),
          "/Login": (BuildContext context)=> new SignIn(),
          "/MyTabs": (BuildContext context)=> new MyTabs()},

  ));
}
```

And then my SignIn contains a google button that when pressed:

```
onPressed: () {  _testSignInWithGoogle(). //async returns FirebaseUser
                          whenComplete(()=>Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/MyTabs")
                          );
                        }
```

and the Drawer from update 1 is included within MyTabs build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

First : Use a stateful widget
Override the initState method like this :

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => new _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  String _currentUserName;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    doAsyncStuff();
  }

  doAsyncStuff() async {
    var name = await _getCurrentUserName();
    setState(() {
      this._currentUserName = name;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_currentUserName == null)
      return new Container();
    return new Text(_currentUserName);
  }
}
```

Second : Use the FutureBuilder widget
Basically, it's a wrapper for those who don't want to use a stateful widget. It does the same in the end.
But you won't be able to reuse your future somewhere else.

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FutureBuilder(
      future: _getCurrentUserName(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData)
          return new Text(snapshot.data.toString());
        else
          return new Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Explanation :
Your getCurrentUserName is asynchronous. 
You can't just directly mix it with other synchronous functions.
Asynchronous functions are quite useful. But if you want to use them, just remember two things :

Inside another async function, you can `var x = await myFuture`, which will wait until `myFuture` finish to get it's result.

But you can't use `await` inside a sync function.
Instead, you can use 
`myFuture.then(myFunction)` or `myFuture.whenComplete(myFunction)`. `myFunction`  will be called when the future is finished. And they both  `.then` and `.whenComplete` will pass the result of your future as parameter to your `myFunction`.

Comment: I am already using a statefulwidget with a state, is it correct to create multiple states for multiple methods in the same class? or should I only update the existing state?  I have also tried to build my drawer in a separate class. The three options actually work but with some errors on the debug console, but first I am trying to understand which is the correct way to go if you have multiple states?

Comment: Flutter is all about composition. If you have something as generic as an Authentification, you can think of spliting that part into a stateful widget.
Something like : Root > ... > MyAuth > ... > SomethingThatNeedAuth. 

Then implement a static method MyAuth.of(BuildContext) => _MyAuthState.  And you should be good.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the part where I create the static method.

Comment: I have updated the OP with my code, please check it.

Comment: Your exception is because you're not checking if the user is logged or not.
Logging is asynchronous. Which means you must test if you're logged or not.

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing this right, but can you kindly check my new update to the post?

Answer (score 1):

"How to properly implement authentification" ?
You should definitely not do it this way. You'll have tons of code duplication.

The most ideal way to organise layers such as Authentification is like this :

```
runApp(new Configuration.fromFile("confs.json",
  child: new Authentification(
    child: new MaterialApp(
      home: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text("Hello"),
          new AuthentifiedBuilder(
            inRoles: [UserRole.admin],
            builder: (context, user) {
              return new Text(user.name);
            }
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
));
```

And then, when you need a configuration or the current user inside a widget, you'd do this :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var user = Authentification.of(context).user;
  var host = Configuration.of(context).host;
  // do stuff with host and the user
  return new Container();
}
```

There are so many advantages about doing this, that there's no reason not to do it. 
Such as "Code once, use everywhere". Or the ability to have a generic value and override it for a specific widget. 
You'll realise that a lot of Flutter widgets are following this idea. 
Such as Navigator, Scaffold, Theme, ...

But "How to do this ??"
It's all thanks to the `BuildContext context` parameter. Which provides a few helpers to do it.
For exemple, the code of `Authentification.of(context)` would be the following :

```
class Authentification extends StatefulWidget {
    final Widget child;

    static AuthentificationData of(BuildContext context) {
        final AuthentificationData auth = context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(AuthentificationData);
        assert(auth != null);
        return auth;
    }

    Authentification({this.child});
    @override
    AuthentificationState createState() => new AuthentificationState();
}
```

Comment: May I ask you, when you said "You should definitely not do it this way.", were you referring to the way of checking if the current user logged in, or the whole idea of implementing an outside function _testSignInWithGoogle() to sign in the user?

Comment: It was all about "Don't mixt potatoes with apples". One class, one job. 
You'll have many problems during the development of your app if you don't split things. Such as copy pasted code, which makes things hard to maintain/debug.

Another example : What if you want to add Unitary Tests, with a simulated user ? 
With my example, I can just instantiate a "TestAuth" class that inherit from "Authentification" class. Override a few methods. And everything's done. But you ? You'd have to rewrite everything.